# Placing a dot over an existing image in PHP

Tags: php, image, pixel

I'm busy making a map that specify's points. 
What im trying now is placing a dot on a specified point.

What's the best way to do this? I've been searching all over the internet and I just can't find a solution to it.

Thanks in advance.

Ps. All images are .jpg's, changing them is not really an option since there are like 5k different images..

How I fixed it:

test.php

```
test.php //To make map with dot on it

$im=imagecreatefromjpeg("map/$x$by$y.jpg");     
$black=imagecolorallocate($im,255,10,10); // defining the color of the dot
$dot=imagefilledellipse($im,$puntX,$puntY,10,10,$black); // drawing the dot of 10x10 at (40,40) coordinate of the image
header("content-type: image/jpeg");  // setting the header
imagejpeg($im);  // generating the new image
```

map.php

```
map.php //Where drawing all images around it
for($y = $startingImageY + $imagesY; $y > $startingImageY; $y--){
for($x = $startingImageX; $x < $startingImageX + $imagesX; $x++){
if(file_exists("map/$x$by$y.jpg")){
    if($y == $centerImageY+1 && $x == $centerImageX){

    echo "<img src='test.php?run=getCenterMap&coordinateX=$coordinateX&coordinateY=$coordinateY' alt='' />";
    } else {
echo "<img src='map/$x$by$y.jpg' alt='' />";
}
} else {
echo "<img src='map/black.jpg' alt='' />";  
}
}echo "<br />";}
}
```

Comment: if you have solved the problem and did not use either of the provided answers, please *add an answer of your own*, and check it as accepted.  Otherwise, you can mark one of the other answers as the one that helped you most.

Answer (score 2):

Would drawing a small circle with the help of GD do the trick?

Here's a brief tutorial on how to use GD: http://www.design-ireland.net/article/Basic_Shapes_in_PHP_GD

Comment: That would do if I could place it on top of my image, that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: @Mark: Read up on GD or ImageMagick. In your PHP you read the image into GD, manipulate it, then output the result as a new image. When searching the internet, focus less on "place over existing" and more on "modify existing".

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal I've been trying that for a while now but still can't get it to work.
Could you post an example using .jpg images? That might help me out since im really stuck on this.